# What is the History of Math Overflow?

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow

I have read vague references to mathoverflow being integrated with stackexchange. Was mathoverflow a separate company or something? Whats the story?

Comment: Why don't you ask that on meta.MO instead?

Comment: Some basic facts can be found in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathoverflow) about MathOverflow.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not active on Math Oveflow

Comment: You're not very active here either, so what? MO is now on the SE network, so you don't need much in order to join in and post the question on meta.MO (you do have 200 points on physics.SE so you will immediately have +100 bonus there, and thus access to the meta site).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would this be a better question to ask on Math Overflow?

Comment: @JoeHobbit Asaf already answered that with his first comment: meta.MathOverflow is the natural place for this question. By definition, it is the site *about MathOverflow*. This site is *about Mathematics.SE*.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing was StackOverflow, for programmers to help each other. Perhaps some offshoots for other topics had already happened, but MO was set up on SE 1.0 and running by September 2009. This place, MSE, started roughly a year later, for all levels of mathematics.

MO is now an SE 2.0 site, but with some legal documentation that allows MO a good deal of self government. The most important difference is that MO is by and for mathematics researchers, mostly graduate students and professors. Most people use their real names. There are enough people active on both sites that lots of very difficult questions asked on MSE are handled here.

Well, probably enough. I'm going to sleep now. I will check this again i the morning, but I imagine you will have lots of information from others by the time I wake up.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9543/mathoverflow-2-0-is-a-comin?rq=1